# Form Submit - Preventing page reload jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm building a contact form and i want to submit the data through ajax and display the result back via the same. But whenever user clicks on submit button, the page seems to be submitting automatically. I have used jquery's **preventDefault** and **stopPropogation** too. But its still not working. I'm new to jQuery and I might be missing something small. Here's the code:

**Form**

```
<form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="contactform" id="contactform">
        <p>Name<br/><input type="text" name="cname" value="" id="cname" required /></p><br/>
        <p>Email<br/><input type="email" name="cemail" value="" id="cemail" required /></p><br/>
        <p>Message<br/><textarea name="cmessage" cols="40" rows="10" id="cmessage" required ></textarea></p>

        //Re-captcha code here
        <p><input type="submit" name="contact_submit" value="Submit" id="contact_submit"  /></p>
        </form> 

        <br />
        <div id="result"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$("#contact_submit").click( function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();




 });

 $("#result").html('');

 $("#contactform").validate();


 });
```

I have included jQuery Validation Plugin which also isn't working.

Comment: Try with `$("#contactform")`, jQuery needs a `#` to identify id and `.` for class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery needs a `#` to identify id and `.` for class.

If you do not want to submit the form use this:

```
$("#contactform").on('submit', function(e){

    alert("not submited");
    return false;

    });
```

Comment: I have added the # before the form id. But it still isn't working. The form is being submitted

Comment: Did you change to ("#contactform")?

Comment: Yes i changed it. But its still the same. Its not working. Also, yes i have included the jQuery script.

Comment: Check here, the validation is ok, not submiting untill all is inserted. http://jsfiddle.net/eTzSb/

Comment: I don't have a problem with validation. The form still is being submitted/page is refreshed.

Comment: Ok, just changed my answer.

Comment: @Sergio, it might be nice to also include the simpler `return false` method for preventing the default action, in your answer.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, sure will do that.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually want is to capture the `submit()`, and `preventDefault()` on that.

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can take a look at. First, change from type="submit" to type="button". That gives you all the same functionality without the submit. Second, if you're trying to get this to work in IE, it's not working because IE doesn't have the preventDefault method on the event object. You can just set the returnValue to false.

```
$("#contactform").submit( function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   if(e.preventDefault){
      e.preventDefault();
   }else{
      e.returnValue = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is normalized in jQuery and will handle Internet Explorer. This is redundant and non crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio is right.

Also, the click listenter will never work on the input either, the right selector is

```
$('input[name="contact_submit"]')
```