# How to submit form without reloading the page

Tags: jquery

I have been cracking my head over this. I have a form that I need to submit via jquery without reloading the page.    `
    Somehow , the form will not submit unless I remove the callback function. But I also need this callback function to prevent the form from reloading. Any idea please? Thanks

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="some.php">
        <input type="file" name="filename" />
        <input type="button" id="button" />
    </form>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $(document).on("click", "#button", function(){
        //Perform some operations then submit the form
        $("#myForm").submit(function(e){  //Somehow, this part of the code is not running unless
            e.preventDefault();           // I remove the callback function
            alert("form submitted!");    // I also need the callback function to prevent page reloading                           
                });
           });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: please, take a look in [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094763/ajax-form-cannot-prevent-page-reload-with-event-preventdefault/25094921#25094921) answers

Comment: Your code's a bit muddled. You're binding the submit event when the form is submitted by the button click, which makes no sense. I'd try removing the outer event registration (click)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var site_url = "page url that you hope to load";
    $("#content").load(site_url);//#content is that div your page'll be load
    });
    });

    </script>
    //try this one,
```